# How to structure data in simple banking application with Firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database, nosql

I want to use Firebase to create a really simple bank, but since I am new to NoSQL databases, I am not sure how to structure the data.

The data I need is very simple.

> The main object is a bank. The bank has accounts. The accounts have
>   names, balances and transactions. Transactions have references to the
>   sending and receiving accounts and an amount and date.

The tricky thing for me, is I'm not sure how to structure the database such that I can connect an account to the transactions it has been involved in.

In an SQL database, I would simple create a table of transactions and use account numbers in the sender and receiver fields. Then I can find all transactions of account `123` with a simple

```
SELECT *
FROM transactions
WHERE sender = "123" OR receiver = "123"
```

How do I do this with Firebase?

Answer (score 1):

You have to denormalize your data see [here](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-04-12-denormalizing-is-normal.html)

In your specific case I would store reference to transaction to both both accounts. Something like this:

```
trasactions:
{
   transaction_by_autoID: {
       ... //transaction data
   },
   .... // all transactions here
}

accounts:
{
  AUTO_ID: {
    my_transactions:{
        ref_to_transaction: true,
        ....
    },
  },
  ....
}
```

looking at the bove you can get all transactions by specific user via the following url:

```
http://yourfirebase.com/accounts/{account_ID}/my_transactions
```